# free will studies in long term decisoin making

Tags: neuroscience, decision-making, free-will

[this wikidepia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroscience_of_free_will) has a list of experiments and discussion around free will in neuroscience. One thing it notes is that there aren't studies focused on long term decision making in relation to free will.

Is that so? Are there any bodies of studies related to free will when it comes to longer time frames?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/10982/7001.  In any case, as I pointed out in my answer, countless experiments in psychology test long-term free will decisions, and humans repeatedly prove to be highly predictable.